# use of access modifier like underscore in python module control how variable defined or module, function, class imported should be accessed?

Tags: python, metaprogramming

Python doesn't have any mechanism that effectively restricts access to any instance variable or method. Python prescribes a convention of prefixing the name of the variable/method with single or double underscore to emulate the behaviour of protected and private access specifiers.

```
class Employee(object):
    def __init__(self, name, sal):
        self._name=name  # protected attribute 
        self._salary=sal # protected attribute
```

while this mechanism is used in Object Oriented programming , my question is can we use this approach to convey other developers that how I want the access of a variable or an imported module in my python module.

In a company I worked long back we had a practice to use `_` with a  variable or an import if we want to tell the developers that I do not want this variable or module I imported here to be access from outside this module.

if it is the way to tell how I want to define the access of variable or a module or function or class I import from elsewhere into my module. Is it documented somewhere ? (like in ieee.org)

```
**some_module.py**

from some_module_api import preset as _preset

.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting the Python Style Guide [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id36):

> In addition, the following special forms using leading or trailing
> underscores are recognized (these can generally be combined with any
> case convention):
>
> `_single_leading_underscore`: weak "internal use" indicator. E.g.
> `from M import *` does not import objects whose names start with an
> underscore.
>
> `single_trailing_underscore_`: used by convention to avoid conflicts
> with Python keyword, e.g.
>
> `tkinter.Toplevel(master, class_='ClassName')`
>
> `__double_leading_underscore`: when naming a class attribute, invokes
> name mangling (inside class `FooBar`, `__boo` becomes `_FooBar__boo`;
> see below).
>
> `__double_leading_and_trailing_underscore__`: "magic" objects or
> attributes that live in user-controlled namespaces. E.g. `__init__`,
> `__import__` or `__file__`. Never invent such names; only use them as
> documented.

You should follow these conventions as otherwise you can both confuse other coders, or write code subject to break in the future (like inventing double underscored "magic" names).

As for imported names into your code, respect the hints from other coders, unless you have strong reasons not to. When defining aliases from imported names with `as`, the same rules apply to the aliases that are now names in your own module.

Comment: yes, double underscore wasn't my concern , I never import or reuse them, my serious concern was before I question someone I should check myself. I think we all need to keep revisting pep style guide. When I tend my variable at module level should not be touched from there module, I add `_` leading underscore. but people question me why you have a leading underscore infront of variable or a function .

Comment: Either the team is not following the Python common set of conventions, because fro example they all come another programming language mindset, or you are being too strict in applying the rules.

Comment: This rules are many times relaxed because everything is public anyway, and if you want to kind of protect access to something, you can use properties for example; you start with public names and than add wrapper logic that validates writes or makes names read-only.

Comment: But the single underscore prefix to signal implementtion detail  looks advantageous to me.

Comment: There is some space to debate here, like with namespace protection of module names. You are free to decide doing `from x import y` instead of being precise with the origin like with `import x` and `z = x.y`.

Comment: that's usually preferred and should be the way to go.